# How to Split worksheets in excel file using VBA, with each new worksheet having an additional drop down list tab

Tags: excel, vba

```
  Sub SplitEachWorksheet()
  Dim FPath As String
  FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
       ws.Copy
       Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & ws.Name & ".xlsx"
       Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
   Next
       Application.DisplayAlerts = True
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
```

I was using a VBA code that splits each worksheet into separate files (see above) however the problem is all the worksheets in the original file rely on one worksheet that have dropdown list values. (ie. if the worksheets were: monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, dropdown lists), so by using the below vba code the dropdowns for monday through fridays worksheets are not working. How can I alter this code so that a copy of the dropdown worksheet/tab carries over with each worksheet? Or is there another solutions so that I can keep the dropdown list values in each tab and be able to split the file?

this code only separates each worksheet individually, but I need each worksheet in the file to split with a copy of a dropdown list tab that is found in the original file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Export Worksheets With Additional Same Worksheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportWorksheets()
    
    Const CopyWithAll As String = "DropDown Lists"
    
    Dim DoNotCopy() As Variant: DoNotCopy = Array(CopyWithAll) ' add more!?
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = wb.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As String
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        wsName = ws.Name
        If IsError(Application.Match(wsName, DoNotCopy, 0)) Then
            wb.Worksheets(Array(wsName, CopyWithAll)).Copy
            With Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite, no confirmation
                    .SaveAs FolderPath & wsName
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                .Close False
            End With
        End If
    Next ws
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Worksheets exported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```